# Some example of __assume leading to a faster code other than "no default" in switch?

Tags: optimization, visual-c++, visual-studio-2005, compiler-optimization

The documentation for `__assume` says "The most common use of `__assume` is with the default case of a `switch` statement, as shown in the following example.".

- Is there any other case where `__assume` can lead to more efficient (or even different) code?
- When inside of an `if / else`, isn't the compiler automatically "assuming" what is already known because of the `if` condition?

I was unable to find any non-trivial examples that show any of above - I hope someone else could.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Consider the following code, compiled with the [`/Ox`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/59a3b321.aspx) switch:

```
if (1) {
  printf("live code\n");
} else {
  printf("dead code\n");
}
```

The optimizer will optimize away the `else`.  Now consider:

```
int x = 1;
if (x == 1) {
  printf("live code\n");
} else {
  printf("dead code\n");
}
```

The optimizer will once again optimize away the `else`.  Also consider:

```
int x = 1;
__assume(x != 1);
if (x == 1) {
  printf("live code\n");
} else {
  printf("dead code\n");
}
```

The optimizer will optimize away the `if` this time -- incorrectly so.

To test, build a test program in Release mode (with the [`/Ox`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/59a3b321.aspx) and [`/Zi`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/958x11bc.aspx) options) and look at the generated assembly (`Alt+8` in Visual Studio.)

Now consider the above `if/else` condition being tested in an inline method.  In certain contexts, the programmer may know that the inline method is called with a particular value and the optimizer may not have realized this fact.  Using `__assume` at the caller level in the manner illustrated above, just before the inlined method is called, can theoretically help the optimizer.

From [Optimization Best Practices](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/optimization-best-practices) (quote from older version):

> __assume has been in Visual C++ for
> multiple releases, but it has become
> much more usable in Visual C++ 2005.
> With __assume, a developer can tell
> the compiler to make assumptions about
> the value of some variable.
>
> For example __assume(a < 5); tells the
> optimizer that at that line of code
> the variable a is less than 5. Again
> this is a promise to the compiler. If
> a is actually 6 at this point in the
> program then the behavior of the
> program after the compiler has
> optimized may not be what you would
> expect. __assume is most useful prior
> to switch statements and/or
> conditional expressions.
>
> There are some limitations to
> __assume. First, like __restrict, it is only a suggestion, so the compiler
> is free to ignore it. Also, __assume
> currently works only with variable
> inequalities against constants. It
> does not propagate symbolic
> inequalities, for example, assume(a <
> b).

Comment: Since __assume is documented as a compiler hint, I would think the behavior you show (optimizing out the else clause) is a bug.  Were you able to see that with just one compiler, and have you seen it with newer versions of msvc?

Comment: @Garen, the behaviour shown is consistent with documentation, why do you __assume it to be a bug?  Feel free to try it out with your favourite MSVC flavour, IIRC the above was tested with VC2010.

Comment: @Garen: It's a bug in the source to tell the compiler to `__assume` something that isn't true.  It's a suggestion in terms of actually optimizing any later code, but it's also a *promise* that the assumption is true.  If you lie to the compiler, it's your fault, not the compiler's, if the resulting code runs the `else` branch instead of the `if` branch in this case.